# Failing to optimize unet model with dtype=torch.float16

Tags: pytorch, stable-diffusion, half-precision-float

I'm trying to use null text inversion with stable diffusion 1.5(or sdxl 1.0) with  data_type=torch.float16, and get "black image". It works well on float32. After debugging, I find the grad turn to zero in unet layers due to it's float16 dtype.
This is the grad of unet first up_block in float32:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JlXK.png)
This is the grad of unet first up_block in float16:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBR7u.png)
The grad is to small so that some turns to zero, causing the following layers smaller and smaller, and finally to zero.

I tried to enlarge the loss by a factor of 10(or 1e3, 1e4), or lr to smaller, but all failed.
How can i do to solve it? I want to use it with torch.float16 o(╥﹏╥)o

Comment: with torch.float16, usually we would have GradScaler to go with it. You can read more [here](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/recipes/recipes/amp_recipe.html)